# Failed to decode basic authentication token Python 3.10

Tags: python, api, http, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I am creating script to send calls to API endpoints via simple python functions. I have the following function to retrieve my OAuth2 token (I will remove the URLs and credentials and nevermind the padding)

```
def get_new_token():
auth_server_url = "my auth url here"
client_id = "my client id here"
client_secret = "my secret here"
auth_headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
token_req_payload = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
token_response = requests.post(auth_server_url,
                           data=token_req_payload, verify=False, allow_redirects=False,
                           auth=(client_id, client_secret), headers=auth_headers)
```

I am then successfully retrieving token with the following line:

```
return token_response.json()["access_token"]
```

Then, I can successfully make a request to one of the endpoints, here is my function (also, nevermind the padding):

```
def call_api_v1_accounts(token):
api_call_headers = {
                    'Content-Length': '10204',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'User-Agent': 'removed',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}

data = {"here": "is my payload"}
api_call_response = requests.post(my_url, headers=api_call_headers, data=json.dumps(data), verify=False)
print(api_call_response.text)
```

This request go through fine and I retrieve the information I need, here is the sample of response (I also removed actual data due to security reasons)

```
{"timestamp":"2022-08-09T10:24:29.713Z","account":{"id":"omitted"},"web":{"href":"omitted"},"sdk":{"token":"omitted"},"workflowExecution":{"id":"omitted","credentials":[{"id":"omitted","category":"ID","omitted":["WEB","API","SDK"],"api":{"token":"ommitted]}]}}
```

Here is my problem, finally. I have another function which uses the same token, function is below (nevermind the padding)

```
def call_api_netverify_acquisitions(token):
api_call_headers = {
    'Content-Length': '10204',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'User-Agent': 'removed',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token}
data = {'mydata':'ishere'}
api_call_response = requests.post(my_url, headers=api_call_headers, data=json.dumps(data), verify=True)
print(api_call_response.text)
```

And the response I receive with it is the following:

```
{"message":"Failed to decode basic authentication token.","httpStatus":401,"requestUri":"endpoint_url_here"}
```

I really have no idea what's wrong with that? I printed the len(token) and it returned 867 so I decided I need to add one more symbol to that (so it can be divided by 4), I've added "=" or "===" or "=======" and the result is the same. I understand that one function uses 'Bearer' and other one uses 'Basic', but I still have no idea what to look for.

I am really struggling, please help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Bearer` instead of `Basic`?

Comment: @KlausD. no, because in such case I get this: {"message":"Basic authentication token is required.","httpStatus":401,"requestUri":"url"}

Comment: @t3ranops - As KlausD pointed out, it should be Bearer instead of Basic. The token which you are passing is an OAuth one which is going to give the authz to the user with it.

Comment: @SrinathMenon thank you for your comment. No, it should not be Bearer. Because the API documentation specifically asks for Basic token and also see the error message in my comment above